High memory usage in Java 21 compared to Java 8
We recently upgraded from Java 8 to Java 21 and noticed a significant increase in memory consumption in our Java applications. Our applications are deployed in containers based on Alpine OS, and we use the Eclipse Temurin Build.
Reproducing the Issue
I have created a small project that replicates this issue, which is available at: https://github.com/RaghuChandrasekaran/java21-memory-usage.
The docker stats report the following memory usage for the Java process when the heap values are -Xms256m -Xmx512m with the memory limit of 1 G.

Analysis
To investigate the issue, I enabled Native Memory Tracking (NMT), and the output is provided below.
Java 8
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1929874KB, committed=393190KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB) 
 
-                     Class (reserved=1099014KB, committed=57566KB)
                            (classes #10367)
                            (malloc=1286KB #10537) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1097728KB, committed=56280KB) 
 
-                    Thread (reserved=31968KB, committed=31968KB)
                            (thread #32)
                            (stack: reserved=31829KB, committed=31829KB)
                            (malloc=106KB #186) 
                            (arena=32KB #58)
 
-                      Code (reserved=253118KB, committed=20810KB)
                            (malloc=3518KB #5282) 
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=17292KB) 
 
-                        GC (reserved=1738KB, committed=890KB)
                            (malloc=26KB #174) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1712KB, committed=864KB) 
 
-                  Compiler (reserved=159KB, committed=159KB)
                            (malloc=24KB #469) 
                            (arena=135KB #7)
 
-                  Internal (reserved=1844KB, committed=1844KB)
                            (malloc=1812KB #12019) 
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB) 
 
-                    Symbol (reserved=15183KB, committed=15183KB)
                            (malloc=11915KB #122017) 
                            (arena=3268KB #1)
 
-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=2366KB, committed=2366KB)
                            (malloc=7KB #90) 
                            (tracking overhead=2359KB)
 
-               Arena Chunk (reserved=196KB, committed=196KB)
                            (malloc=196KB) 

Java 21
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=2044186KB, committed=424038KB
       malloc: 42596KB #337605
       mmap:   reserved=2001590KB, committed=381442KB

-                 Java Heap (reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB) 
 
-                     Class (reserved=1050068KB, committed=13012KB)
                            (classes #17813)
                            (  instance classes #16553, array classes #1260)
                            (malloc=1492KB #45190) (peak=1496KB #45058) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1048576KB, committed=11520KB) 
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=131072KB, committed=69376KB)
                            (    used=68992KB)
                            (    waste=384KB =0.55%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1048576KB, committed=11520KB)
                            (    used=11130KB)
                            (    waste=390KB =3.38%)
 
-                    Thread (reserved=31927KB, committed=2831KB)
                            (thread #32)
                            (stack: reserved=31826KB, committed=2730KB)
                            (malloc=66KB #191) (peak=79KB #207) 
                            (arena=34KB #60) (peak=2322KB #38)
 
-                      Code (reserved=249888KB, committed=24908KB)
                            (malloc=2200KB #9067) (at peak) 
                            (mmap: reserved=247688KB, committed=22708KB) 
 
-                        GC (reserved=1734KB, committed=882KB)
                            (malloc=22KB #80) (peak=250KB #137) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1712KB, committed=860KB) 
 
-                  Compiler (reserved=238KB, committed=238KB)
                            (malloc=74KB #835) (peak=117KB #857) 
                            (arena=164KB #4) (peak=53061KB #30)
 
-                  Internal (reserved=863KB, committed=863KB)
                            (malloc=827KB #25496) (peak=835KB #25298) 
                            (mmap: reserved=36KB, committed=36KB) 
 
-                     Other (reserved=24KB, committed=24KB)
                            (malloc=24KB #3) (peak=58KB #5) 
 
-                    Symbol (reserved=30116KB, committed=30116KB)
                            (malloc=28254KB #234525) (at peak) 
                            (arena=1862KB #1) (at peak)
 
-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=5362KB, committed=5362KB)
                            (malloc=87KB #1569) (peak=87KB #1568) 
                            (tracking overhead=5275KB)
 
-        Shared class space (reserved=16384KB, committed=11996KB, readonly=0KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=16384KB, committed=11996KB) 
 
-               Arena Chunk (reserved=2KB, committed=2KB)
                            (malloc=2KB #116) (peak=55748KB #1365) 
 
-                    Module (reserved=127KB, committed=127KB)
                            (malloc=127KB #3158) (at peak) 
 
-                 Safepoint (reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=8KB, committed=8KB) 
 
-           Synchronization (reserved=1751KB, committed=1751KB)
                            (malloc=1751KB #17227) (at peak) 
 
-            Serviceability (reserved=17KB, committed=17KB)
                            (malloc=17KB #9) (peak=17KB #11) 
 
-                 Metaspace (reserved=131387KB, committed=69691KB)
                            (malloc=315KB #118) (at peak) 
                            (mmap: reserved=131072KB, committed=69376KB) 
 
-      String Deduplication (reserved=1KB, committed=1KB)
                            (malloc=1KB #8) (at peak) 


The possible suspects that I had were,

Direct Buffer/ Native Memory usage by Netty
Default Memory Allocation Library in Alpine

But testing with the spring-pet-clinic project which doesn't use Netty ruled out #1 and testing in Ubuntu Base OS ruled out #2.
What additional steps can I take to further diagnose the cause of this behavior?
Update on Oct 2nd:
As per @matt's request, I tried with a Simple HTTP Server in Native Java without any dependency and can reproduce the same behavior (Java 21 using slightly higher memory than Java 8). In this case, the memory usage is not as high as in the Spring Pet Clinic. Changes are updated in the https://github.com/RaghuChandrasekaran/java21-memory-usage repo.


Did you try with a very simple program to see if the difference in the JVM itself?

@matt The Spring Pet Clinic itself is a simple http-based server and I believe the issue is happening only in Containers.

You could start a simple http server. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html Then you don't need any dependencies.

@matt I've tried with a Simple HTTP server and have updated findings in the post.

I am not facing same issues.

Cloned https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic main branch and executed ./mvwn package with openjdk-21.0.2
Generated docker build java21
Cloned https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/releases/tag/1.5.x and executed ./mvwn package with openjdk-8u242b08
Generated docker build java8

Then I ran both docker's with the commands you specified on github repository
Executed docker stats

infallible_driscoll is java8
gracious_clarke is java21


java8 results:
Connected to remote JVM
JVM response code = 0

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1930424KB, committed=396664KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1099019KB, committed=57571KB)
                            (classes #10364)
                            (malloc=1291KB #10885)
                            (mmap: reserved=1097728KB, committed=56280KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=31968KB, committed=31968KB)
                            (thread #32)
                            (stack: reserved=31829KB, committed=31829KB)
                            (malloc=106KB #186)
                            (arena=32KB #58)

-                      Code (reserved=253651KB, committed=24267KB)
                            (malloc=4051KB #5485)
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=20216KB)

-                        GC (reserved=1738KB, committed=890KB)
                            (malloc=26KB #174)
                            (mmap: reserved=1712KB, committed=864KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=159KB, committed=159KB)
                            (malloc=24KB #504)
                            (arena=135KB #7)

-                  Internal (reserved=1841KB, committed=1841KB)
                            (malloc=1809KB #11987)
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=15190KB, committed=15190KB)
                            (malloc=11921KB #121974)
                            (arena=3268KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=2374KB, committed=2374KB)
                            (malloc=7KB #90)
                            (tracking overhead=2367KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=196KB, committed=196KB)
                            (malloc=196KB)


java21 results:
Native Memory Tracking:

(Omitting categories weighting less than 1KB)

Total: reserved=2075752KB, committed=427820KB
       malloc: 42667KB #338045
       mmap:   reserved=2033085KB, committed=385153KB

-                 Java Heap (reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=524288KB, committed=262208KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1050065KB, committed=13009KB)
                            (classes #17806)
                            (  instance classes #16545, array classes #1261)
                            (malloc=1489KB #45243) (peak=1492KB #45058)
                            (mmap: reserved=1048576KB, committed=11520KB)
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=131072KB, committed=69568KB)
                            (    used=69098KB)
                            (    waste=470KB =0.68%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1048576KB, committed=11520KB)
                            (    used=11126KB)
                            (    waste=394KB =3.42%)

-                    Thread (reserved=63422KB, committed=4674KB)
                            (thread #32)
                            (stack: reserved=63321KB, committed=4573KB)
                            (malloc=66KB #191) (peak=79KB #207)
                            (arena=34KB #60) (peak=2322KB #38)

-                      Code (reserved=249970KB, committed=26666KB)
                            (malloc=2282KB #9141) (at peak)
                            (mmap: reserved=247688KB, committed=24384KB)

-                        GC (reserved=1734KB, committed=882KB)
                            (malloc=22KB #80) (peak=250KB #137)
                            (mmap: reserved=1712KB, committed=860KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=211KB, committed=211KB)
                            (malloc=47KB #819) (peak=64KB #843)
                            (arena=164KB #4) (peak=43583KB #28)

-                  Internal (reserved=865KB, committed=865KB)
                            (malloc=829KB #25631) (peak=835KB #25331)
                            (mmap: reserved=36KB, committed=36KB)

-                     Other (reserved=28KB, committed=28KB)
                            (malloc=28KB #3) (peak=62KB #5)

-                    Symbol (reserved=30121KB, committed=30121KB)
                            (malloc=28259KB #234655) (at peak)
                            (arena=1862KB #1) (at peak)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=5374KB, committed=5374KB)
                            (malloc=92KB #1650) (at peak)
                            (tracking overhead=5282KB)

-        Shared class space (reserved=16384KB, committed=11996KB, readonly=0KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=16384KB, committed=11996KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=2KB, committed=2KB)
                            (malloc=2KB #116) (peak=45340KB #1149)

-                    Module (reserved=128KB, committed=128KB)
                            (malloc=128KB #3160) (at peak)

-                 Safepoint (reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=8KB, committed=8KB)

-           Synchronization (reserved=1748KB, committed=1748KB)
                            (malloc=1748KB #17209) (at peak)

-            Serviceability (reserved=17KB, committed=17KB)
                            (malloc=17KB #9) (peak=17KB #11)

-                 Metaspace (reserved=131386KB, committed=69882KB)
                            (malloc=314KB #117) (at peak)
                            (mmap: reserved=131072KB, committed=69568KB)

-      String Deduplication (reserved=1KB, committed=1KB)
                            (malloc=1KB #8) (at peak)





Category
Java 8 - Committed Memory in KB
Java 21 - Committed Memory in KB
Diff (Java 21 - Java 8)




Heap
262208
262208
0


Class
57571
13009
-44562


Thread
31968
4674
-27294


Code
24267
26666
2399


GC
890
882
-8


Compiler
159
211
52


Internal
1841
865
-976


Symbol
15190
30121
14931


Native Memory Tracking
2374
5374
3000


Arena Chunk
196
2
-194


Other
0
28
28


Shared Class Space
0
11996
11996


Module
0
128
128


SafePoint
0
8
8


Synchronization
0
1748
1748


Serviceability
0
17
17


Metaspace
0
69882
69882


String Deduplication
0
1
1



I executed a heapdump and it shows java21  consuming less memory than java8
JAVA21

JAVA8

Why does Native Memory Tracking (NMT) report Java21 as consuming more memory than Java8? To be transparent, I do not know. Probably someone has the answer to that from Java8 to Java21 many changes have been done even in the reporting and capturing data so I guess Java21 is capturing more data...
Java8 reports as classes while Java21 reports it as Metaspace

@VmI11 Can you please try with https://github.com/RaghuChandrasekaran/java21-memory-usage and let me know if you see the same result?

Thats the one I ussed

In the docker stats, I can see a 9% memory difference. But in your case, it seems Java 8 is using more.
